# My Cat Growls at Me When I'm Outside

Tags: cats, vocalizations

I have an indoor cat who has no problem with me when I'm inside. She'll come up to me, let me pet her, etc. She even sleeps on my side of the bed when I'm out.

But whenever I go outside and pass by her window she hisses and growls at me through the window. It seems odd, because if I come in immediately, she won't even be bothered by me, even if I'm still wearing any jacket, hat, or gloves I may have been wearing outside. It seems to be just me being outside. The window puts her about 6 feet above the ground.

Why is she be bothered by me when I'm outside?

Comment: She isn't sure it's you. She can't smell you, and that makes a big difference. Have you tried talking to her so she hears your voice, or letting her smell you through a window screen?

Comment: Yeah. When the window is open, I say her name, tell her who I am, even reach up to let her smell my hand through the screen. She still is quite skittish, and after sniffing usually slinks away.